# After reinstall grub, it looks for menu.lst in /boot/boot/grub folder?

Tags: grub

Basically, after I reinstalled `grub-legacy` (grub1), it expected to have `menu.lst` at `/boot/boot/grub/menu.lst` instead of `/boot/grub/menu.lst`

Thus, when I reboot the system, it stops at the grub command console and I need to manually run `configfile /grub/menu.lst` to load the configuration file.

I have temporarily symlinked `/boot/boot/grub/menu.lst` to `/boot/grub/menu.lst`, but I want to know why reinstalling `grub` made it look for `menu.lst` in `/boot/boot` instead of `/boot`

One thing I can think of is that I have separate partitions for `/boot` and `/`, though I'm not sure whether that makes a difference.

The commands I used to reinstall grub were:

```
bash> grub
grub> root (hd1,0)
grub> setup (hd1)
```

where:

- `hd1,0` is my `/boot`
- `hd1,1` is my `/`

Before reinstalling `grub-legacy`, I had `grub2` installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected the reason is the separate **"boot"** partition.
The right place for **menu.lst** (e.g. where grub-legacy expects to find it) is in the **/boot/grub** folder on the **"boot"** partition: **(hd1,0)/boot/grub**.
When you mount your **"boot"** partition into **/boot** folder of the **RootFS**, this will translate to:
**/boot/boot/grub/menu.lst**.

Instead of linking **/boot/boot/grub/menu.lst** (right place) to **/boot/grub/menu.lst** (wrong place), move your whole **/boot/grub** folder to **/boot/boot/grub**. This way the **/boot/grub** folder of your **"boot"** partition will be in the right place. After that you may symlink **/boot/boot/grub** to **/boot/grub** for convenience.

In short: grub-legacy expects to find **/boot/grub** folder with **menu.lst** on your **"boot"** partition. Which in turn is mounted in **/boot** folder of your **RootFS** partition.

I hope I managed to explain this clearly enough.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Though, I'm looking for a solution for grub to look in /boot/grub for menu.lst. The reason is "update-grub" is still expecting to find menu.lst in /boot/grub.

Comment: I believe the default location is compiled (hardcoded) in the grub binary. You may be able to check it with this command: `strings $(which grub) | grep menu.lst` (this may prove me wrong on my answer, if so, I may edit the answer with more details)

Comment: @Patrick, the usual solution I've seen is for the "/boot" partition's root directory to have a symlink "boot" pointing to itself, i.e. `cd /boot; ln -s . boot`.

Comment: @0xAF, you're right. Grub binary looks for menu.lst in two locations 1) /menu.lst 2) /boot/grub/menu.lst, but I didn't see /boot/boot/grub/menu.lst ...

Comment: @mlp, thank you for the workaround, but this doesn't solve the mystery why after reinstall grub, it looks for menu.lst in /boot/boot/grub/menu.lst

Comment: @Patric, grub is always looking there, these are the default locations, the fix suggested by mlp is actually the commonly used practice in most linux distributions. For some reason the link is missing in your installation and probably the files are not in the right place. Note: now that you confirmed the menu.lst location, I'm sure this is default location for (at least) most linux distributions. About why it is different than the normal install... perhaps there are different installation methods when grub is installed by OS installator and when you install it via package manager.